# Latin words are changing direction when copy and paste arabic sentence from word to notepad

Tags: c#-4.0, gdi

when i try to copy arabic text from window word to notepad. alphabetic and numeric characters are changing the direction. below screenshot is from word. 
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fsF2U.png)

and result is **الغذائية لون E 120 اللون**

in word it is showing **120E** but after paste it into notepad it shows **E 120**

please help why it is rendering like that. in my application customer is coping the data from the word and pasting it into textbox control. there is changing the direction.

Comment: That's what it's supposed to do. Arabic is written from right to left, but numbers are left to right, like English text. This has to be bi-directional.

Comment: but when i copy and paste from word, why it is changing the direction.

Comment: do you know any library which supports similar rendering as MSword, so i can use it.

Comment: Sorry, I completely misunderstood the question. I can't duplicate this error in Windows 10. You would have these problems if your application is not Unicode compatible. I don't have C# 4 though. I thought C# 4 is Unicode compatible and uses a standard Edit box, unless there is some odd settings. If your application wasn't Unicode compatible then it couldn't even save the Arabic text.